# How to delete all local mail from a system account?

Tags: unix, cron, email

The root mail account has been blown up by mischieveous cronjobs, and I want to completely delete the mail from the account. Is there a key for that in the mail command?

I deleted /var/mail/root but I don't know if that's the proper way to do it, or if the `root` file needs to be recreated manually.

**Update** I recreated the `root` file with 660 and root:mail ownership, I'll see if this is needed to let the root account get mail again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted method is:

```
cat /dev/null > /var/spool/mail/root
```

Your method should have worked, but you might need to restart sendmail (or whatever) as it might have choked on the brief lack of file.

Comment: I should have noted my platform: I'm on Solaris 9 atm and /var/spool/mail/ doesn't exist in this environment.

That said, restarting sendmail fixed the issue.

Comment: @Luke has no name: It's still /var/spool/something iirc, and you can still cat /dev/null. That basically does the same thing as deleting the file, but it preserves the file with all of it's permissions, etc.

Comment: Or just `> /var/spool/something/blah`